# Passing parameters in a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, link-to

Ok this one is going to sound really trivial but I can't seem to get it right. I just want to pass a parameter :invite_code with the link_to from the view to an un-related controller.

view:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Join', :action => 'invite', :invite_code => project.invite_code , :method => :post %></td>
```

routes:

```
match 'invite' => 'database#invite', :via => :post
```

database_controller:

```
def invite ...
  puts params
end
```

The debug output on the console goes as follows:

```
{"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"..........", "action"=>"invite", "controller"=>"database"}
```

Everything works fine except that I can't seem to pass the the parameter. I am rookies but I have been stuck on this way too long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<%= link_to "Join", invite_path(invite_code: project.invite_code), method: :post %>
```

You might need to update your route:

```
post 'invite' => 'database#invite', as: :invite
```

Comment: Alright, I am ashamed now. It worked perfect. I am really not used to all that magic at work in rails out of the box.